# Ruby SQL Syntax Checker

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlplus

I'm looking for a ruby-based (Not Rails) SQL syntax checker. My program takes .sql files then passes them to sqlplus using backticks like so:

> `sqlplus username/password@database myfile.sql`

The sql file always includes the lines

> WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 1
>   WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1

but they don't seem to catch if you do something like misspelling SELECT. I would like my code to be able to scan the sql file and raise an error before trying to run sql plus, but I don't want to write a whole checker myself. Is there a gem or similar that anyone knows of that I can use?

Comment: Why do you not want Rails? There should be relevant code in it.

Comment: I've been asked to do it in Ruby so that it can be integrated with programs that are already being used that were made without Rails.

Comment: Rails' component ActiveRecord can be used without Rails.